# Updating the contents of a dropdown list Javascript/PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu

I'm new to Javascript/Jquery and struggling with a certain issue.

In the process of adding a job to a database, the users have an option to update the contents of dropdown lists with new options.  Adding the new options is handled through a greybox which posts data with PHP through to the database.

After adding the new option it does not display in the dropdown list.  As such they need to be able to click a button to refresh the contents of the dropdown list.  Has anyone accomplished this before, and can show me some sample source code?  Or is there a more elegant solution fo this issue?

I've been researching pretty much non-stop and cannot find a solution, any help is appreciated.  n.n

Edit:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
function getbrands(){  
   new Ajax.Request('ajax/brand.php',{  
        method: 'get',  
        onSuccess: function(transport){  
            var response = transport.responseText;  
            $("brand").update(response);  
        }  
    });  
}
```

It works... sometimes.  Highly unstable.  Also has a bad habit of conflicting with other scripts on the page.  (mainly the greybox)

Any suggestions will be taken on board at this stage.  :X

Comment: Do you have any code samples? What have you tried so far?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    function getbrands(){
       new Ajax.Request('ajax/brand.php',{
            method: 'get',
            onSuccess: function(transport){
                var response = transport.responseText;
                $("brand").update(response);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

It works... sometimes.  Highly unstable.  Also has a bad habit of conflicting with other scripts on the page.  (mainly the greybox)

Any suggestions will be taken on board at this stage.  :X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your using jQuery, you could do the following..

```
//in a php file that your gonna use to fetch new dropdown values
<?php //pathToPhpFile.php
    header("Content-Type: application/json");

    //here you'd perform a database query 
    //heres a dummy dataset
    $data = array(  
        array( "id" => "dropdown1", "label" => "Dropdown #1"), 
        array( "id" => "dropdown2", "label" => "Dropdown #2"), 
    );

    echo json_encode( $data );
    exit;
?>
```

javascript code: sould be wrapped in $(document).ready( function(){ }); block to ensure the button is ready to accept events

```
//attach refresh event to button 
$("#refeshButtonId").click( function() {

    var dropdown = $('#idOfTheDropdown');

    //fetch the key/values pairs from the php script
    jQuery.getJSON( "pathToPhpFile.php", function( data ) {

        //empty out the existing options
        dropdown.empty();

        //append the values to the drop down
        jQuery.each( data, function(i, v) {
            dropdown.append( $('<option value="'+ data[i].id +'">'+data[i].label+'</option>');
        });
    });

});
```

refined code :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready( function(){

        $("#refeshButtonId").click( function() {

            //fetch the key/values pairs from the php script
            jQuery.getJSON( "pathToPhpFile.php", function( data ) {

                 var dropdown = $('#idOfTheDropdown');

                //empty out the existing options
                dropdown.empty();

                //append the values to the drop down
                jQuery.each( data, function(i, v) {
                    dropdown.append( $('<option value="'+ i +'">'+ v +'</option>') );
                });
            });

        });    
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That looks hot.  :]  
I'm going to try that now.  n.n

Comment: let me know how it goes, one thing to note is the data structure of the values returned via the php code. If your not using associated arrays you would need to change the 
    data[i].id & data[i].label 
to 
    data[i][0] & data[i][1] etc

Comment: I'm a bit new to all this... but from what I understand I attach the #refreshButtonID() function to an onclick on the hyperlink?

The SQL query in the php file returns an array like the following - Array([id] => brand [id] => brand ....etc )

Desperately trying to come up to speed with Jquery, so your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Also, the code inspector says that there is an error in the row ~ "dropdown.append(...etc).  I can't track it down.  I copied yours word for word.

Comment: AHh yeah my bad, theres a missing ) near the end of the dropdown.append line so it should be 

dropdown.append( $('<option value="'+ data[i].id +'">'+data[i].label+'</option>') );

Comment: Still no luck at this point.  I'll continue debugging, if you have any pointers glad to receive!

Comment: Hmm the $("#refeshButtonId").click link is attaching an onclick event to the element on the page with an id attribute of "refeshButtonId" (note the element id shouldnt have #). So you need to give the element that you want to perform the refresh each time its click an id of "refreshButtonId" eg <a id="refreshButtonId" href="#">Refresh</a>

Comment: if your php array is returned in the form you stated you would need to use dropdown.append( $('<option value="'+ i +'">'+ v +'</option>') );

Comment: I edited post to show a code block with script tags that you should be able to copy and paste in the head of the document:
To things to note are the #refreshButtonId and #idOfTheDropdown these should be the id attributes of their respective elements, the refresh link and dropdown list

Comment: This is looking really good.  The only issue I'm experiencing now is that the options aren't being placed inside the existing dropdown list.  Will update if I fix this myself.  :)

Comment: Have noted that dropdown.empty() is actually deleting the dropdown box.  Giving the append nothing to apend to.

Comment: empty() removes all child elements so its possible you have the id on an element wrapping around the select element?. should be <select id="idOfTheDropdown"><options>...</options></select>

Comment: Yessssss. :D
I am your number one fan.  Thanks for making me infinitely smarter with jquery and webdev in general.  I'll be able to make use of this knowledge in heaps of places.  

Thanks again!

Comment: Hey no problem, least I can do to help out a fellow kiwi ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use ajax to post the data to your php file, echo the html for the new dropdown back to the javascript, and then use jquery to put in the new contents. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

no sample code but I guess it goes like this

1. after the posting, create a callback
   that updates the DOM, particularly
   the options for the select box

maybe it goes something like this in code
in jquery:

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  data : $('#newjobfield').val(),
  dataType: 'text'
  success : function(data){
    $('#selectbox').append('<option value="' + data + '">' + data + '</option>')
  }
});
```

in php

```
function getNew()
{
 if ($_POST)
 {
    // update database 
    // then echo the record's 'name' (or whatever field you have in there)
    echo $newInsertedJobName;
  }
  die();
}
```

Now this code sucks, so just tell me if something does not work (I haven't tested it, cuz I made it a few minutes ago, while at work :P)